# PhpUnit funciona com Programação Estruturada?

Tags: php, phpunit, programação-estruturada

Bom dia, tenho um trabalho de faculdade que você deve fazer testes unitários, e para isso estou usando o PHPUnit, a pequena aplicação que criei para realizar estes testes é composta apenas por programação estruturada(sem orientação á objetos) mas em todo tutorial que acabei encontrando no YouTube eles apenas demonstram aplicações usando orientação a objetos.

Gostaria de saber se consigo fazer os testes unitarios mesmo assim com esta aplicação programada estruturadamente ou terei que trocar para uma Orientada á Objetos para terminar meu trabalho? Se caso não existe outra ferramenta de testes unitários em PHP que possa realizar testes em uma aplicação estruturada?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode sim testar códigos não OO com PHPUnit, testes unitários não estão vinculados somente ao paradigma de Orientação a Objetos, este tipo de teste (como o nome já diz) testa as unidades do seu código, no caso de OO é um método por exemplo, no seu caso pode ser um simples arquivo com um código lá dentro.

Por exemplo, você tem esse código:
**simple_add.php**

```
$arg1 = $_GET['arg1'];
$arg2 = $_GET['arg2'];
$return = (int)$arg1 + (int)$arg2;
echo $return;
```

Você pode testá-lo dessa forma:

```
class testSimple_add extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    private function _execute(array $params = array()) {
        $_GET = $params;
        ob_start();
        include 'simple_add.php';
        return ob_get_clean();
    }

    public function testSomething() {
        $args = array('arg1'=>30, 'arg2'=>12);
        $this->assertEquals(42, $this->_execute($args)); // passes

        $args = array('arg1'=>-30, 'arg2'=>40);
        $this->assertEquals(10, $this->_execute($args)); // passes

        $args = array('arg1'=>-30);
        $this->assertEquals(10, $this->_execute($args)); // fails
    }

}
```

Para este exemplo foi declarado o método `_execute` que aceita um *array* de parâmetros GET, onde o mesmo captura e retorna ao invés de de incluir em cada um várias vezes. Logo depois é comparado a saída utilizando os métodos de `assertion`do *PHPUnit*.

Claro que, o terceiro `assertion` vai falhar (dependendo do erro reportado),
por causa que o *script* testado irá retornar um `Undefined index error`.

E claro que quando testando, você deve colocar o `error_reporting` como `E_ALL | E_STRICT`.

fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021254/php-testing-for-procedural-code

Comment: Perfeito! Muito obrigado.